# How can I check if a view is really visible on screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Many examples with ScrollView, but I don't have any idea with RelativeLayout

In RelativeLayout, some views will cover another view.
I can check it in xml, but how can check it with java code?
Use isShown(), willNotDraw(), hasWindowFocus(), getLocalVisibleRect(), those are not working.

**Case1: Container layout is really on screen**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--container layout is really on screen-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Case2: Container layout is not really on screen**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--container layout is not really on screen-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
   if (myView.isShown()) {
        // Its visible
    } else {
        // Either gone or invisible
    }
```

Comment: In case2, container is VISIBLE. but it is not show on screen

Comment: @ShengMaoLee that's true after taking a look at the source code it only verifies that its attached to a view parent.

Answer (score 0):

**Change in Case2: Container layout is not really on screen**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--container layout is not really on screen-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- fragment -->
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private LinearLayout container;
    private RelativeLayout parent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);

        //container.bringToFront();
        Log.e(TAG, "container: " + parent.indexOfChild(container));
        Log.e(TAG, "frameLayout: " + parent.indexOfChild(frameLayout));

        if (parent.indexOfChild(container) == parent.getChildCount() - 1) {
            Log.e(TAG, "container is visible");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "container is not visible");
        }
    }
}
```

If container index is equal to child count in parent then it is front of other view and is visible. otherwise container is overlapped behind other layout.

I hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: thanks, I know how to show container, but i want to know how to check it.